# How to view Attribute Code and Override them

Tags: acumatica

One of our client requested customization is for a dynamic list of Activity Statuses (In the Activity Module, and other modules that have 'Activities' button) that is dependent on the selected Activity Type. Upon inspecting the code, There is a [ApprovalStatus] attribute, there is also [TaskStatus] attribute used across other module, and maybe more?.

I wish to ask how can we view these attributes (I believe they are stringlist with codes and conditions) so that we can customize/override them properly. If this is possible. If this is not possible or you advise against it, please explain to us why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a graph extension of any base Acumatica graph in the customization project editor and click on the View Source button:
[image]

You can use the Find feature from the Find In Files tab to locate the source code of the Attributes:
[image]

If all you want to do is to filter the drop down list values, there's no need to dig into the attribute. You can use the SetList method to dynamically set  the values shown in the drop down list based on your business rules:
[PXStringListAttribute](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=426773d0-8861-2fe4-d789-0d7d41f8bae9)

Comment: If you have no choice but to modify the attributes, you can either create a new one that herits from the base one or copy/paste the code if you need to redefine private constructs. Try to avoid it as it's not standard practice and could be looked upon when certifying your solution.

Comment: we wish to have different sets of lists for each type of activity type. is this feasible?

Comment: Yes, if the list is a subset of the existing types PXStringListAttribute.SetList should be enough. If you introduce new types you'll have to modify the code which uses those values.